# flex-box how to have a static fixed column to the right of multiple flex-rows?

Tags: css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/xrdwRw

Currently the CSS is producing this:
[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is this, with flex-box still working and without using floats with don't work with flex-container[image]

**Markup**

```
<div>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import "compass/css3";
// .dashboard { float: left; }
.col {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the outer div a flex container (and remove `float` from `.col`)

CSS

```
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="flex-outer">
  ....
</div>
```

*Updated*

Based on a comment I updated my answer, cleaned up the code and used proper flex properties.

Also, since prefixed properties weren't set on the flex item rules, I removed them from the flex container rules, as they won't do anything when not set in both places.

Stack snippet

```css
@import "compass/css3";
.flex-outer {
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 25px;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-outer">
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin-left: 1em; for .col as the finishing touch ;)

Comment: @Gerard Done :)

Comment: Thanks, this works as far as placement goes, but in the other answer, the flex-items still flex and expand

Comment: @LeonGaban Yes, well remove `-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;` and add `flex-shrink: 0;` from mine and it does too. I didn't changed that cause I though you wanted them to wrap when there is no space. If not, they will overlap each other and that looks really bad

Comment: @LeonGaban Updated my answer and also cleaned up code and used proper flex properties

Comment: @LeonGaban Thank you very much

Comment: @LGSon With your example, how would you keep the width of the right element from shrinking and just let the left element shrink?

Comment: @JohnnyQ Answered your question how-to :)

Comment: Two years later...what would be the proper way (today in 2019) to make `.col` wrap at a certain breakpoint? @LGSon?

Comment: @ShawnSpencer Not much changed...`@media` query's and `min-width` (and for flex items, `flex-wrap: wrap` allowing them to actually wrap)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex: 1 0;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: orange;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 1 0;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dashboard">
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="flex-container">
      <li class="flex-item">1</li>
      <li class="flex-item">2</li>
      <li class="flex-item">3</li>
      <li class="flex-item">4</li>
      <li class="flex-item">5</li>
      <li class="flex-item">6</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```